# Access matrix values by X and Y coordinates

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have coordinates in an matrix (an image) that I want to change, I have the coordinates in the form of a x coordinates vector and a y coordinates vector. How do I change the values of only those coordinates.

I've tried to use the notation `I(x,y)` but it gives me all the possible combinations:

```
I = zeros(10,10);
x = [4 6 8];
y = [7 3 1];
I(x,y) = 1;
imshow(I);
```

gives me: [image] while what I want to get is:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `sub2ind` function like the following:

```
I(sub2ind(size(I),x,y)) = 1
```